# Optimizing gulp watch task

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm new to gulp and I've got a couple of gulp questions that I hope are pretty easy (meaning I'll probably have one of those forehead smacking moments when I hear the answer)...

My gulpfile has a number of repetitive one-way copy tasks, and then I'm watching these separate tasks in the watch command, however I'm almost certain that the way I'm doing it is totally inefficient.

Also, I'm noticing some interesting behavior, the copy command for syncHtmlRootDir task works exactly as I hoped (it will delete files as necessary), but none of my other one way copy tasks will remove deleted files, and I'm guessing it's a pathing issue, but I'm stumped on it.

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss   = require('gulp-minify-css')
var uglify        = require('gulp-uglify');
var newer       = require('gulp-newer');
var path        = require('path');
var del         = require('del');


function handleError (error) {
  console.log(error.toString())
  this.emit('end')
}


//setup browerSync to serve from both src and dist directories.
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: ["./", "src"] //  ./ signifies root of folder, allows to load files from dist and src folders.
    },
  })
});


//one way sync of root folder
gulp.task('syncHtmlRootDir', function(done) {
  return gulp.src(['src/*.html'])
  .pipe(newer('dist/'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({
    stream: true
  }))
});


//one way sync of app folder
gulp.task('syncHtmlAppDir', function(done) {
  return gulp.src(['src/app/**/*'])
  .pipe(newer('dist/app/'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/app/'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({
    stream: true
  }))
});

//one way sync of image folder
gulp.task('syncImgDir', function(done) {
  return gulp.src(['src/assets/img/**/*'])
  .pipe(newer('dist/assets/img/'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/img/'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({
    stream: true
  }))
});


//copy and compile SCSS code
gulp.task('compileSass', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/assets/css/**/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass())
  .on('error', handleError)
  .pipe(minifyCss()) 
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/css'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({
    stream: true
  }))
});


//minify JS
gulp.task('uglifyJS', function() {
  gulp.src('src/assets/js/**/*.js')
  .pipe(uglify())
  .on('error', handleError)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/js'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({
    stream: true
  }))
});



//watch tasks
gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync'], function() {
  var rootDir = gulp.watch('src/*.html', ['syncHtmlRootDir']);
  rootDir.on('change', function(ev) {
    if(ev.type === 'deleted') {
      del(path.relative('./', ev.path).replace('src','dist'));
    }
  }); 

  var appDir = gulp.watch('src/app/**/*', ['syncHtmlAppDir']);
  appDir.on('change', function(ev) {
    if(ev.type === 'deleted') {
      del(path.relative('./', ev.path).replace('src/app/','dist/app/'));
    }
  }); 

  var imgDir = gulp.watch('src/assets/img/**/*', ['syncImgDir']);
  imgDir.on('change', function(ev) {
    if(ev.type === 'deleted') {
      del(path.relative('./', ev.path).replace('src/assets/img/','dist/assets/img/'));
    }
  });

  var jsDir = gulp.watch('src/assets/js/**/*', ['uglifyJS']);
  jsDir.on('change', function(ev) {
    if(ev.type === 'deleted') {
      del(path.relative('./', ev.path).replace('src/assets/js/','dist/assets/js/'));
    }
  });

  var cssDir = gulp.watch('src/assets/css/**/*', ['compileSass']);
  cssDir.on('change', function(ev) {
    if(ev.type === 'deleted') {
      del(path.relative('./', ev.path).replace('src/assets/css/','dist/assets/css/'));
    }
  });  

});
```

So I'm 1) looking to combine my repetitive copy tasks into fewer tasks 2)have the delete file function work on all copy tasks and 3) optimize my watch task function to reduce repetition.

p.s., I've also noticed that if I add new files to the watch folders, it won't "recognize" them until I restart the watch command, so my method of syncing isn't exactly bulletproof. =/

Your thoughts are most appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: My first question would be why? this is a dev environment only thing where optimization has very little if any benefit

Comment: Yes, it is a dev environment, true, but it just seems like my methods of performing the tasks are seriously bloated, so for my own gulp learnings, I'm sure there are better ways to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: maybe, but your better off using your time learning to optimize your application.  dev environment optimization is less about performance and more about making your life easier as a developer.

Comment: Good points, no argument here. I would like to be able to get to a point with gulp however where I wouldn't be embarrassed to show off my gulp skills in a team environment, if that makes sense, and I'm pretty sure I'm not there yet.

Comment: I work in enterprise, no one will judge your task runner optimization.  Seriously, with task runners or things like it, no one cares how, they just care what it does and if it works / if it makes their life easier. Besides, most frameworks these days have taskrunner level things built into them unless you're working on something fairly unique.  Gulp is a little outdated IMO.

Comment: Well that's good to hear.. and I am trying to update my skill set, so if you feel that gulp is a bit outdated, would you have any suggestions on something else I should be looking into? ;)

Comment: depends what you plan to be working on. Webpack is a good thing to know if you're talking webdev which it looks like you are.  But if you plan on workin in big frameworks like react or angular, they generally have this stuff scaffolded already in the framework.

Comment: Well, this is probably a better conversation to be had offline, but briefly, I'm needing to update my skills, and most front end dev roles these days require knowledge of angular / gulp (or grunt / webpack), etc etc, so having had some previous experience with gulp, I've been trying to brush up on it. Webpack seems a bit more convoluted to me, but I will tackle that after gulp, unless you think it's better to push it higher on my priority list.

Comment: gulp is a hammer, webpack is a nailgun. one's easier to learn and use for a small job, one lets you build at the enterprise level.

Comment: Ok, thanks Bryan, I appreciate the info. :)